# Characterization of a square matrix.

Tags: matrices, reference-request

I would like to see a proof to this fact.

For a square matrix the following are equivalent:

- $A$ has a right inverse.
- $A$ has rank $n$, where $A$ is $n \times n$.
- $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proof involving abstract linear algebra. View $A$ as an operator on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. If $B$ is a right-inverse to $A$, then $A \circ B = \text{id}_V$. Thus, $B$ is injective, and an injective map from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself must be surjective, so $B$ is both injective and surjective, implying that $B$ is invertible. The left-inverse of an invertible map must be its inverse, so $A$ is invertible. Then $A$ must be surjective, so it has rank $n$. All of these steps are reversible, giving the desired equivalences.